# Datatables hide/show class in rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to toggle the visibility of some divs or spans in my Datatables rows (I cannot work with hiding/showing columns) when an event is triggered.

here is approximatly my script
https://jsfiddle.net/pxLmth7f/

I have a DataTables table with 500 rows.\

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="testbutton">hide/show</button>

<table id="tableUserTest" class="dataTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>7958<span class="table-evo">some stuff</span></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- many more rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each row contains a span.table-evo inside (the one I am trying to toggle)\

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testbutton").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".table-evo").toggle();
  });
  $('#tableUserTest').DataTable();

});
```

I have a button to toggle this class, which triggers event.

Awaited result : all rows get their span.table-evo toggled.
However it only affects the visible rows.

I've read that it's not good to directly use jquery to change Datatables instance, however I was unable to find a solution without using hiding/showing columns from the api, and same on stackoverflow :(

Any help welcome :)

cheers

Comment: Without details to hand: look at the datatables row render callback.  When it renders the row, hide/show as required.  Alternatively, if this is for *all* rows in the table, then add a class to the table's parent div and use css.  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wLuyohdj/

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the advice, I actually didn't think about this simple trick, but it works fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataTables API as follows:

```
$("#testbutton").on("click", function(e) {
  var nodes = myTable.cells( ':has(.table-evo)' ).nodes().to$();
  $(".table-evo", nodes).toggle();
});
```

The `myTable` variable assumes you have defined your DataTable and assigned it to a variable:

```
var myTable = $('#tableUserTest').DataTable( {...} );
```

The following command...

```
myTable.cells( ':has(.table-evo)' )
```

...selects all those DataTables cell which contain any child elements having the `table_evo` class. DataTables supports jQuery selectors in this function.

The `nodes()` function then selects the `<td>` DOM nodes for those DataTable cells.

This operates across the entire data set in your DataTable - not just the rendered DOM elements which are on the current page. This is important, as it means we are operating on the whole set of nodes we need to toggle - even those which are not displayed, due to DataTables paging.

The `to$()` function converts these DOM nodes into jQuery objects.

After that, you can perform the `toggle()` on the class in the selected nodes: `$(".table-evo", nodes).toggle()`.